# Jssor Freeze API

Tags: jquery, jssor

I have a Jssor slider with the following options:

```
var defaults = {
  $AutoPlay: true,
  $AutoPlaySteps: 1,
  $Idle: 0,
  $SlideDuration: 20000,
  $SlideEasing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear,
  $PauseOnHover: 4,
  $DragOrientation: 1,
};
```

The "Freeze" on hover works perfectly, but I am looking for an API method to do the same thing.  The closest I have found is $Pause, but this appears to wait for the end of the current SlideDuration before actually stopping.

Is there any way to achieve an instant freeze of the slider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I've hacked it together like so in jssor.slider.mini.js

Between:

```
h.$Pause=function(){P=l};
```

And:

```
h.$Play=function(){if(!P){P=d;C[s]&&C[s].Bc()}};
```

I added the following:

```
h.$Freeze=function(){F=1;ic()};
```